# "swallowed the bowl"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Or like the woman who was watching a lush imbibing dry martinis at a Third Avenue bar in New York City. The drunk downed the contents of each cocktail glass at one gulp, daintily nibbled and **swallowed the bowl**, then finally turned the glass over and ate the base.

I can't get the meaning of the expression highlighted in bold.

I understand the words separately.

- to swallow - to move food into your stomach by the muscles of your throat
- a bowl - a round container for food.

I thought whether it could mean that he consumed the drink wholly. But I am doubting that martini is served in bowls.

Could you help me out?

Comment: Swallow = to move ANYTHING that will fit into your stomach using the muscles of your throat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He swallowed the upper part of the martini glass (the bowl), and then ate the lower part (the base).

He ate the upper part piece by piece: he **nibbled** it.

> [image]

The upper part, the **bowl**, contains the drink. The **base** is the **foot** that ensures that the glass stays upright on the table.

Some people like to impress others by eating the glass after drinking from it. This is a video from a Russian wedding: [a man eats a glass at a wedding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCiazGXW_M8). As you can see, he **nibbles** it and eats it piece by piece.

In another video, [a student eats a glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAq8R5Vh-N0).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What's the upper part? is it somehow detached from the rest of the drink?